# При добавлении записи возникает 500

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

Вот проперти (у меня на MySQL):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pavilion
spring.datasource.username=pavilioner
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Вот контроллер:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class AnimalController {
    private final AnimalService service;
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("animals", service.getAll());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Главная");
        return "index"; 
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model model) {
        return "add"; 
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String save(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String poroda, @RequestParam String age, Model model) {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName(name);
        animal.setAge(age);
        animal.setPoroda(poroda);
        service.save(animal);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Вот HTML c Thymeleaf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div><h2>Добавить животное</h2></div>
    <div><a href="/">Животные</a></div>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <div>Животное: <input type="text" name="poroda"></div>
        <div>Имя: <input type="text" name="name"></div>
        <div>Возраст: <input type="text" name="age"></div>
        <div><button type="submit">Добавить</button></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" выкидывается вот что:

**Whitelabel Error Page**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Feb 19 20:08:52 MSK 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Посмотрите на то, что при этой ошибке выводится в консоль, там явно будет указано, что пошло не так. Если не разберётесь, добавьте по крайней мере стектрейс в вопрос.

Comment: @Byb , я запаниковал. На самом деле для теста я сначала добавил значение вручную через SQL, потом просто забыл его удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Я удалил запись, которую добавил вручную через SQL. То есть мне она мешала присвоить ID моей первой записи, добавленной через форму HTML. Проблема решена.